# JPA: How to select a binary(16) UUID by a String UUID?

Tags: spring, jpa, uuid

I have the following Entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Comment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid4")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "uuid4")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID imageId;

    private Instant creationTime;

    private String text;
}
```

And a CRUD repo:

```
public interface CommentsRepository extends CrudRepository<Comment, UUID> {

    List<Comment> findAllByImageId(final UUID imageId);
}
```

I add some example data:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CommentsSampleData implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final CommentsRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public CommentsSampleData(final CommentsRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        createComment("617220ff-1642-4490-b589-869e7978c5e0", Instant.now(), "comment1");
        createComment("617220ff-1642-4490-b589-869e7978c5e0", Instant.now(), "comment2");
        createComment("617220ff-1642-4490-b589-869e7978c5e0", Instant.now(), "comment3");
        createComment("e3a8aa57-6937-4f9e-b117-78bafe61b718", Instant.now(), "comment1");
    }

    private void createComment(
            final String imageId,
            final Instant creationTime,
            final String text) {
        final Comment comment = new Comment();
        comment.setImageId(UUID.fromString(imageId));
        comment.setCreationTime(creationTime);
        comment.setText(text);

        log.info("save comment: {}", comment);

        repository.save(comment);
    }
}
```

So the data in my table looks like the following:

[image]

So what is the best way now to select by those binary UUID's?
I will get string UUID's from the frontend So I guess I somehow need to convert those Strings to Binaryies. Whats the best way to do so so that it also works with ids and primary keys.

Example endpoint:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class CommentsController {

    private final CommentsService service;

    public CommentsController(final CommentsService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/comments", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Comment> getComments(@RequestParam("imageId") final UUID imageId) {
        log.info("get comments by imageId: {}", imageId);

        String existingIds = service.findAll().stream()
                .map(Comment::getImageId)
                .map(UUID::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

        log.info("Image Id Passed: {}", imageId);
        log.info("Existing image ids: {}", existingIds);

        String resultIds = service.findAllByImageId(imageId).stream()
                .map(Comment::getImageId)
                .map(UUID::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

        log.info("Result image ids: {}", resultIds);

        return service.findAllByImageId(imageId);
    }
}
```

When I now do a request:

```
localhost:8080/comments?imageId=617220ff-1642-4490-b589-869e7978c5e0
```

I get no result even though the UUID exists but not as string, it exists as binary(16) in the database:

```
d.f.a.c.service.CommentsController       : Image Id Passed: 617220ff-1642-4490-b589-869e7978c5e0
d.f.a.c.service.CommentsController       : Existing image ids: 617220ff-1642-4490-b589-869e7978c5e0,617220ff-1642-4490-b589-869e7978c5e0,617220ff-1642-4490-b589-869e7978c5e0,e3a8aa57-6937-4f9e-b117-78bafe61b718
d.f.a.c.service.CommentsController       : Result image ids:
```

Comment: What happens now if you just save your entity as it is with UUID? doesn't auto convert to binary and store it?

Comment: It does. The UUID's are getting stored as binary 16 as shown on the screenshot. The problem is I cant query them. I updated my post with an example endpoint and GET.

Comment: Why are you storing them as binary in the first place? It basically serialized the UUID class. Now if things change this won't work to deserialize anymore. Why not simply store it either as a UUID (if your db supports or) or a char(36)?

Comment: Because storing it as Binary 16 is much more efficient: https://devforth.io/blog/why-your-software-should-use-uuids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It is working as expected without any issue and it is auto converted between UUID and binary.
- I recommend trying the following to make sure that id genuinely exists in database.

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/comments", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Iterable<Comment> getComments(@RequestParam("imageId") 
                                          final UUID imageId) {
        log.info("get comments by imageId: {}", imageId);

        String existingIds = service.findAll()
                .map(Comment::getImageId)
                .map(UUID::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        
        log.info("Image Id Passed : {}", imageId);
        log.info("Existing image ids : {}", existingIds);

        return service.findAllByImageId(imageId);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I updated my post and put in the logging result. I do not get any result.

Comment: I see. I used it with H2 database and is creating the table ass binary-16 and retrieving correctly. What database are you using?

Comment: I was using mysql. I tried it with H2 and you are right. It is working perfectly with H2.

Answer (score 0):

Another way will be

```
@Query(value = "select BIN_TO_UUID(id), comment from comments", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> findIdAndComments();
```

[BIN_TO_UUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_bin-to-uuid) will convert binary(16) to UUID.